# qspatialite error compiling Qgis 1.8 (linux debian squeeze)

Tags: spatialite

I tried to compile Qgis 1.8 in linux debian squeeze (following the instructions in INSTALL.txt). During 'make' I get the following error:

[ 40%] Building CXX object src/providers/spatialite/CMakeFiles/spatialiteprovider.dir/qgsspatialiteprovider.cpp.o
/usr/local/qgis-1.8.0/src/providers/spatialite/qgsspatialiteprovider.cpp: In function ‘bool initializeSpatialMetadata(sqlite3*, QString&)’:
/usr/local/qgis-1.8.0/src/providers/spatialite/qgsspatialiteprovider.cpp:4972: error: ‘spatial_ref_sys_init’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [src/providers/spatialite/CMakeFiles/spatialiteprovider.dir/qgsspatialiteprovider.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]:**  [src/providers/spatialite/CMakeFiles/spatialiteprovider.dir/all] Error 2
make: ** [all] Error 2

Any help to solve this?

Oscar

Comment: Hello, did you solve this? I have exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it compiling libspatialite by myself. I used this version: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-sources/libspatialite-2.4.0-5.tar.gz, and executed the classical ./configure & make & make install

After that, ensure the compiled version of libspatiallite is selected during ccmake step (SPATIALITE_INCLUDE_DIR and SPATIALITE_LIBRARY vars)